# Valid names for new column type

Tags: tables

Is it possible to have a column type name like `AP` or `P1` or anything that is not a single letter?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P1}{p{5in}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{P1}
text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it must be a token. But you can use command names, eg. \AP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it has to be a single token, but you can (although it's a secret) use arbitrary command names not just letters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{\Pa}{p{5in}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{\Pa}
text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! Ended up with something like this: ``\newcolumntype{\Lx}[1]{>{$}L{#1}<{$}} `` (math version of L) and ``\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}``

Comment: @David Carlisle "although it's a secret" .. very funny!! :)